# Call str.format_map from C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

Given a format string and a dictionary, both stored in `PyObject*` variables, how can I call [str.format_map](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) from the C API using these values?

My goal here is to do the equivalent of:

```
# Given the "dict" and "fmt" are already in PyObject*
dict = {'Foo': 54.23345}
fmt = "Foo = {Foo:.3f}"

# How do I get result?
result = fmt.format_map(dict)
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious sequence of `PyObject_GetAttr`, creation of a 1-tuple, `PyObject_Call`?

Comment: @delnan Why is `PyObject_GetAttr` required here?

Comment: I just assumed the `format_map` implementation is `static` or otherwise internal, so you'd have to get it from the `fmt` (or the str type object, if you have a reason to).

Comment: Do you actually need `format_map`? If you know your mapping is a plain `dict`, you may be better served by using it as a keyword argument dictionary to `format`.

Comment: @user2357112 That'd be fine, too, but I also don't know how to call format() with a dictionary from C...  My understanding was format_map was actually cleaner than format in this case, as I'm using a dictionary directly.

Comment: `do_string_format_map` is in [`Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ea4130668150/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h). I'm not sure what best practice is for calling it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this snippet should suffice:

```
PyObject *dict, *value, *result, *fmt;
dict = PyDict_New();
if (!dict)
     return NULL;
value = PyFloat_FromDouble(54.23345);
if (!value) {
     PY_DECREF(dict);
     return NULL;
}
if (PyDict_SetItemString(dict, "Foo", value) < 0) {
     Py_DECREF(value);
     Py_DECREF(dict);
     return NULL;
}
Py_DECREF(value);
fmt = PyUnicode_FromString("Foo = {Foo:.3f}");
if (!fmt) {
     Py_DECREF(dict);
     return NULL;
}
result = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(fmt, "format_map", dict, NULL);
Py_DECREF(fmt);
Py_DECREF(dict);
return result;
```

As you can see, this is cumbersome, so it's best to do as much as possible in Python!

Comment: In Python 3, the only change would be to build a `PyObject*` for `"format_map"`, right?

Comment: In that case, this doesn't compile...  `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs` takes a `PyObject*` for the 2nd arg, not a `const char*` - http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/object.html